# Disabling Bitnami WordPress Server Cache

Tags: wordpress, caching, bitnami

I read through [this doc](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/administration/disable-cache/) on how to disable the caching with a Bitnami WordPress server and made the changes, but the server is still caching changes I make to JS, CSS files. It's driving me crazy because I have to wait 30 seconds before I can refresh. Is there anything else I need to do or missing?

I checked WP as well and didn't see that `WP_CACHE` was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Open `/bitnami/wordpress/manager-windows.exe`, restart the servers to apply settings.

[image]